# jQuery Two form submit buttons?

Tags: jquery, mobile

http://justin.derp.us/
(jquery mobile)

How can I edit it so there is only one?
I've tried playing with both css's and cant seem to break down into one.
[I don't understand the http://justin.derp.us/mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css, its all .ui]
The /css/styles.css I get, but changing it won't do anything because the default one is taking over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `opacity: 0;` to your `#submitButton` style definition in `/css/styles.css`

**UPDATE**

To make the bigger one disappear:

a) Add `opacity: 0; left: 226px; top: 0px;` to your `#submitButton` style definition in `/css/styles.css`

b) Make sure your styles.css is referenced **after** jquery mobile's. If that does not work, add the following inside your  after every other css  tag.

```
<style>
.ui-btn-inner {
   display: none;
}
.ui-btn-up-a {
   border-width: 0;
}
</style>
```

That should do it! :)

Comment: That works fine, but how can I do it to the bigger one? Its the smaller one I was wanting to keep. How can I make it so the bigger one doesn't make the smaller one move as well?

Comment: Still only deleting the small one, not the big one, http://justin.derp.us/ But maybe I didn't understand correctly?
changed it to opacity 100 for the blue one since thats the one I want, but still doesn't look 100% right, but so much closer! thank you! (just need that little blue bit gone, the button moved up a tiny bit, and that grey bar gone, all things in that mobile.css)

Comment: Got it moved up a bit, just did top: -2px; (im assuming the padding from mobile.css messed it up a little)